Naming rule on "Private WithEvents" fields
I have a naming rule that requires private fields to start with an underscrore and have to be in camelCase. This works well except for "Private WithEvents" fields where I get the warning:
Naming rule violaton: Prefix '_' is not expected. 
How can I get rid of the warning?
I defined private fields as
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private 
and also tried
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private, withevents 
I would expect the first one to work for "WithEvents" fields too.
